# Run Selenium Java Code on Jenkins master using shell

Tags: java, shell, selenium, jenkins, javac

I'm trying to run a Java Selenium code on Jenkins using shell command. The Java file needs 3 `.jar` files in order to run. I tired, among other commands,  `Javac "*.jar" myfile.java` which is not working.

I'm pulling the code form a repository and the master node is running RedHat 6. When I run `javac myfile.java` I get the follwoing error messgae:

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
ClusterReloadAut.java:3: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          ^
ClusterReloadAut.java:5: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
ClusterReloadAut.java:6: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                                  ^
ClusterReloadAut.java:11: error: cannot access WebDriver
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           ^
  bad class file: ./WebDriver.class
    class file contains wrong class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile your `myfile.java` into `myfile.class` (so you can run it with `java` command) you need to add a `-cp path/to/selenium.jar` to `javac` command. Like this:

```
javac -cp path/to/selenium.jar myfile.java
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Javac is the java compiler, java is the command used to run java programs. This might be the reason?

Do you see any errors?

Comment: It seems that the selenium jar is not found in the classpath, selenium packages cannot be found.